# Поиск любого символа не совпадающего с заданным

Tags: excel-формулы

Есть строка. Например, "zzzdvdzsf". Как, используя формулы в excel, можно найти порядковый номер первого символа, который НЕ 'z'? (т.е. это будет четвертый символ - символ 'd')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ в соответствии с уточненными условиям. Только формулы Excel и ячейки для хранения промежуточных результатов.

Общий вид тестовой таблицы
[image: Общ вид таблицы]

Используем функции: **НАЙТИ**, **ЕОШ**, **ЕСЛИ**, **ПСТР**.
Для хранения промежуточных результатов используем дополнительные ячейки.
Количество промежуточных ячеек равно количеству символов в строке.

Общий алгоритм, если **Начальная позиция** вхождения **Символа** в **Строке** равна **1**, то следует проверять следующий символ (используем дополнительные ячейки) т.к. за ним может быть также **Символ**.
В каждой последующей ячейки следует уменьшать длину **Строки** для анализа.
Как только **Символ** не находится в **Строке**, то следовательно будет порядковый номер **не Символ**.
Граничные условия длина **Строки**.

1-я итерация
[image: 1-я итерация]

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ(C4;A4));0;
     ЕСЛИ(НАЙТИ(C4;A4)=1;1;
          ЕСЛИ(НАЙТИ(C4;A4)=B4;999;НАЙТИ(C4;A4)+1)))
```

1-я итерация: проводится анализ на граничные условия.

2-я итерация
[image: 2-я итерация]

```
=ЕСЛИ(D4=1;
     ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ($C4;ПСТР($A4;E$2;$B4)));E$2;НАЙТИ($C4;ПСТР($A4;E$2;$B4)));
          D4)
```

Формула, далее тиражируется в последующие итерации и т.д. до 9-ой

9-я итерация
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
=ЕСЛИ(K4=1;
     ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ($C4;ПСТР($A4;L$2;$B4)));L$2;НАЙТИ($C4;ПСТР($A4;L$2;$B4)));
          K4)
```

Результирующий столбец с интерпретацией результатов 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
=ЕСЛИ(L4=1;"строка состоит только из символов " & C4;
     ЕСЛИ(L4=999;"символ " & C4 & " последний в строке";
          ЕСЛИ(L4=0;"символа " & C4 & " нет в строке"; L4)))
```

PS.
Возможно решение одной формулой, но ограничение **MS Excel** позволяет проанализировать только **Строку** в 5 символов.

Общий вид таблицы для 5-ти символов
[image: Общий вид для 5-ти символов]

Формула для 5-ти символов
[image: Формула для 5-ти символов]

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ(C2;A2));0;
   ЕСЛИ(НАЙТИ(C2;A2)>1;
      ЕСЛИ(НАЙТИ(C2;A2)<5;НАЙТИ(C2;A2)+1;999999);
         ЕСЛИ(НАЙТИ(C2;A2)=1;
            ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ(C2;A2;2));2;
               ЕСЛИ(НАЙТИ(C2;A2;2)=1;1;
                  ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ(C2;A2;3));3;
                     ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ(C2;A2;4));4;
                        ЕСЛИ(ЕОШ(НАЙТИ(C2;A2;5));5;
                           999999)))));222)))
```

Comment: Жесть, конечно... Но... Принимается :)

Comment: :) зарядка для мозгов. Одно не ловкое движение и все сначала, не отладишь по шагам

Answer (score 1):

С помощью формул Excel не представляется возможным проанализировать строку вида **zzzdvdzsf** на вхождение **z** (несколько вхождений z), только с помощью функции пользователя.
Код функции:

```
'strSAnlz - анализируемая строка
'strS - символ относительно которого определяется следующий
'возвращается порядковый номер следующего, который после strS
'находится всегда первый символ strS
Function DetNumNextS(strSAnlz As String, strS As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nTemp As Integer
    Dim nPos As Integer
    Dim strTemp As String
    nTemp = 0
    nPos = 0

    'номер позиции Искомого символа в строке
    nPos = InStr(1, strSAnlz, strS)
    Select Case nPos
        'Искомого симовола нет в Анализируемой строке
        Case 0
            DetNumNextS = -1
            Exit Function

        'Искомый символ самый последний в Анализируемой строке
        Case Len(strSAnlz)
            DetNumNextS = 0
            Exit Function

        'Искомый символ самый первый в Анализируемой строке
        Case 1
            DetNumNextS = 0

        'Искомый символ в Анализируемой строке во всех прочих случаях
        Case Else
            DetNumNextS = nPos - 1
    End Select

    strTemp = Mid(strSAnlz, nPos, Len(strSAnlz))
    For i = 1 To Len(strTemp)
            If strS <> Mid(strTemp, i, 1) Then
                    nTemp = i
                    Exit For
            End If
    Next

    DetNumNextS = DetNumNextS + nTemp
End Function
```

Результат работы **DetNumNextS**

[image: Результат работы DetNumNextS]

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за ответ. Но он не является ответом на вопрос. Вопрос я ставил вполне конкретно - `"Как, используя` **формулы** `в excel..."`. Поэтому также и привет всем голосующим за ответ, который таковым не является.

Comment: Тогда прошу уточнить в явном виде, возможно ли использовать дополнительные ячейки MS Excel для хранения промежуточных результатов вычислений?

Comment: Да. Использовать дополнительные ячейки для хранения промежуточных результатов можно.

Comment: >  Roman Sidorin: С помощью формул Excel не представляется возможным проанализировать строку вида zzzdvdzsf на вхождение z (несколько вхождений z), только с помощью функции пользователя.
||| ограничение MS Excel позволяет проанализировать только Строку в 5 символов.|||
Не нужно так категорично. Формульные решения есть (см. ответы)

Answer (score 1):

**Поиск первого символа, не совпадающего с заданным:**

```
=МИН(ЕСЛИ(ПСТР(A1;СТРОКА($1:$99);1)<>"z";СТРОКА($1:$99)))
```

Формула массива, вводится сочетанием трех клавиш *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* Правильно введенная формула массива в строке формул видна в окружении фигурных скобок: *{формула}*

Здесь 99 - число, гарантированно большее максимальной длины анализируемых текстов. Можно вписать 20, 999...

Если в тексте может не быть других символов, формула покажет число *длина_текста+1*. Для исключения такой ошибки можно определять длину текста и усложнять часть *СТРОКА($1:$99)*, но можно проще - добавить искомые символы в конце текста

```
=МИН(ЕСЛИ(ПСТР(A1&ПОВТОР("z";99);СТРОКА($1:$99);1)<>"z";СТРОКА($1:$99)))
```

В таком варанте при отсутствии других символов результат - ноль.

Недостаток показанного варианта решения: не видит различия между прописными и строчными. Но и на этот случай есть таблетка - сравнивать по коду символа:

```
=МИН(ЕСЛИ(КОДСИМВ(ПСТР(A1&ПОВТОР("z";99);СТРОКА($1:$99);1))<>122;СТРОКА($1:$99)))
```

Прошу не забывать - это формулы массива.

'-----------------

Бонус:)

**Счет заданных символов в тексте**

```
=ДЛСТР(A1)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;"z";))
```